# Qt app is not running on AVD

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator

My Qt application is not running on AVD.
When I press the RUN button I got these -->

compile output: http://postimg.org/image/axhst5bzn/full/

Issues —> http://postimg.org/image/6n34xk6wj/full/

AVD starts with home screen and stay in home screen. How can I load or run my application on AVD ?

I'm using Qt 5.2.1 with Qt Creator 3.0.1 on Windows 8.1

Please help me...

Comment: Use Qt Creator 3.1 and retry.

Comment: Thank You... I've installed Qt Creator 3.1 and the problem is solved but facing another problem. The only Qt Widget projects are running and QML or Qt Quick application is not running. The AVD starts with a black blank screen and close it automatically...
How can I solve that ???
Here is the application output.
[link](http://postimg.org/image/y3ova988j/full/)